# How to use a range control in a ion-slide-box page

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework

I am having trouble getting my range controls to function correctly in my ionic app.

I have an application where I want to use ion-slide-box to be able to slide between pages in the app. But when I place a range control on the page I can only change the value of the range control by clicking around on the control. Dragging inside the control doesn't seem to work - probably because the slide-box takes these events first.

The app is to be used on both Android and IOS.

Example codepen is here: http://codepen.io/flemmingdjensen/pen/emzXmB

```
<ion-slide-box>
  <ion-slide>
    <h1>Test of ion-slide-box and range control</h1>
    min <input type="range" style="width:80%"> max
    <br><br>
    page 1
  </ion-slide>
  <ion-slide>
    <br><br>
    page 2
  </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<input type="range" on-touch="enableSlide(false)" on-release="enableSlide(true)" />
```

And

```
$scope.enableSlide = (enable) => { $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.enableSlide(enable); };
```